# How to show that every Suslin tree is Frechet-Urysohn

Tags: general-topology, infinitary-combinatorics

A topological space $X$, is **Frechet-Urysohn**, if, given $x \in \overline A \subset X$, there exists a sequence of points in $A$ which converges to $x$.

I am trying to prove that every [Suslin tree](http://randomperturbation.wordpress.com/tag/suslin-trees/), is Frechet-Urysohn. (I have read in an article, that this claim is folklore).

Any help?

Thank you!

Comment: Upon thinking about this, I wonder if you mean something other than what I wrote (and deleted). Do you mean a Souslin tree itself endowed with some particular topology (_e.g._, the _tree topology_)?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I didn't get to see what you wrote and deleted. I am reading an article and it's said there that "Let $E$ be the one point compactification of Aronszajn-tree with the tree topology".  It is said that this space is Frechet. It is said there that the terminology is taken from Rudin - Set theoretic topology. Any ideas? Thank you!!

Comment: It is also mentioned there that "a tree either contains infinitely many pairwise incomparable elements or can be covered with finitely many branches"

Comment: I definitely originally answered the wrong question. I've now actually answered the correct question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a tree $\langle T , \leq_T \rangle$, the *tree topology* on $T$ is generated by the basis consisting of all sets of the form

- $( \leftarrow , t ] = \{ x \in T : x \leq_T t \}$, for $t$ in $T$;
- $( s ,  t ] = \{ x \in T : s <_T x \leq_T t \}$, for $s < t$ in $T$.

Note that if $t \in T$ has countable height, then there is a countable neighbourhood basis for $t$: take all the intervals $( s , t ]$ where $s <_T t$; since $\mathrm{ht}_T ( t ) = \mathrm{ot} ( \langle \{ x \in T : x <_T t \} , \leq_T \rangle)$ is countable, there can only be countably many different such sets.  (Any $t \in T$ of height $0$ has a smallest open neighbourhood, which is $ ( \leftarrow , t ] = \{ t \}$.)

From this it follows that any tree of height $\leq \omega_1$ is first-countable in the tree-topology, and is therefore Fréchet-Urysohn.  (Souslin, and more generally Aronszajn, trees, have height $\omega_1$.)

---

Somewhat more can be said:

- $t \in T$ has a countable neighbourhood base in the tree topology iff $\mathrm{ht}_T (t)$ is $0$, a successor ordinal, or has cofinality $\omega$.
- For essentially the same reason that no ordinal space $[0,\alpha)$ with $\alpha > \omega_1$ is Fréchet-Urysohn (no sequence in $[ 0 , \omega_1 )$ can converge to $\omega_1$), no tree of height $> \omega_1$ can be Fréchet-Urysohn in the tree topology.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your explanation!