# What can we say about the one point compactification of a Suslin tree?

Tags: general-topology, infinitary-combinatorics

As a continuation to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/765723/can-we-construct-from-0-omega-1-a-space-which-is-strictly-frechet-with-no-w#765799) question:

> The **Alexandroff one point compactification** of $(X,\tau)$, is a space $X \cup \{a\}$, where open neighborhoods of $X$ are $\{ U : U \in \tau\} \cup \{ V \cup \{a\}: V \in \tau $ and $V^C$ is closed and compact in $ X \}$
>
> A tree $T$ is a **Suslin tree** if: 
>   1. The height of $T$ is $\omega_1$.
>   2. Every branch in $T$ is at most countable.
>   3. Every antichain in $T$ is at most countable.

Let $X=T \cup \{q\}$ be the Alexandroff one point compactification of a Suslin tree. 
I am trying to figure out whether $X$ is [Frechet-Urysohn](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/765723/can-we-construct-from-0-omega-1-a-space-which-is-strictly-frechet-with-no-w), and whether ONE wins in [$G_{np}(q,X)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/765723/can-we-construct-from-0-omega-1-a-space-which-is-strictly-frechet-with-no-w).

Any ideas or directions?

Thank you!

Comment: Using the tree topology for $T$ again?

Comment: Yes, the tree topology as Artur Fischer described in in here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759075/how-to-show-that-every-suslin-tree-is-frechet-urysohn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/765862/8348) we have that if $X = \{ \infty \} \cup T$ is the one-point compactification of an Aronszajn tree $T$ with the tree topology, then the sets of the form $$U ( s_1 , \ldots , s_n ) = \{ \infty \} \cup {\textstyle \bigcap_{i \leq n}} \{ x \in T : x \not\leq_T s_i \}$$ where $s_1 , \ldots , s_n \in T$ form a neighbourhood basis at $\infty$.

The basic idea for show that $X$ is Fréchet-Urysohn is to notice first (and Henno Brandsma has) that for each $s \in T$ we have  $\chi ( X , s ) \leq \aleph_0$, and so $X$ is "Fréchet-Urysohn at $s$."

Given $A \subseteq T$, it is relatively easy to show that $\infty \in \overline{A}$ iff either

1. $A$ includes an infinite family of pairwise incomparable nodes of $T$; or
2. $A$ includes an infinite chain with no upper bound in $T$.

(If $U = U(s_1 ,\ldots , s_n )$ is a basic open neighbourhood of $\infty$ and $A$ satisfies either (1) or (2), then there must be points of the antichain/chain which are not below any $s_i$.  If $A$ fails to satisfy either of these conditions, then $A$ is the union of finitely many chains, each of which has an upper bound in $T$, and so $U(s_1 , \ldots , s_n)$ — where the $s_i$ are such chosen upper bounds — is an open neighbourhood of $\infty$ disjoint from $A$.)

In each of the above cases you basically do the obvious thing to construct a sequence in $A$ converging to $\infty$.

(That there is no winning strategy for ONE in $G_\text{np} ( \infty , X )$ is in the linked answer.)

Comment: I see that now. I asked this question before I saw your answer to the previous one. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The fact that $X$ is Fréchet-Urysohn is "folklore" according to [this old paper](http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/105832/CommentatMathUnivCarol_019-1978-1_6.pdf), we only need $T$ to be Aronszajn for this. It's probably not too hard, as $T$ is already first countable.

And neither player has a winning strategy in $G_{np}(X,q)$ according to this [nice survey paper](http://www.auburn.edu/~gruengf/preprints/gamesurv9.pdf) by the author who introduced this game in the first place. It refers the proof to an older paper by Gerlits and Nagy, that might not be available online.

[added] Also see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/765862/4280) which had exactly the same idea, but actually wrote out proofs!

Comment: Yes, indeed :) actually a beutifull proof!